# Is the E8 manifold embeddable in a 4-dimensional simplicial complex?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

The [E8 manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_manifold) is well known for being a compact 4-manifold that is not homeomorphic to a simplicial complex. It is, however, embeddable in one. Specifically, because it is a compact metric space of dimension 4 it can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{9}$ as every compact metric space of dimension $n$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$. However, what is the minimal dimension of a simplicial complex into which E8 embeds? Can it be embedded in a 4 dimensional simplicial complex? If not, is the minimal dimension of a simplicial complex into which E8 can be embedded known?

Comment: It does not embed in a 4-d complex. I do not know about the minimal dimension.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Is the reason behind it not being embeddable in a 4d complex easily stateable? Else, is there a reference?

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $M$ is a closed (compact and with empty boundary) $n$-manifold. Then the image of an embedding of $M$ in any $n$-dimensional simplicial complex $X$ is a subcomplex of $X$.

Comment: Ah, in the sense that we can retriangulate our simplicial complex to contain the image as a subcomplex. Many thanks.

Comment: I think it is a little simpler than that. Consider the union of the $n$-simplices of $X$. By invariance of domain, $M$ must be embedded inside this subcomplex. If $M$ intersects some $n$-simplex $\sigma$, it must entirely contain $\sigma$ because $M \cap \sigma$ is both open and closed in $\sigma$. Hence, $M$ is given by the union of the $n$-simplices it intersects.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Perhaps we're thinking with different sets of assumptions, but if I triangulate $S^{2}$ and give it the weak topology say, I can embed a a copy of the disc $D^{2}$ entirely within the interior of one of the $2$-simplices making up a face of the complex comprising $S^{2}$ without it being the entire face.

Comment: $D^2$ is a manifold with boundary, so you cannot apply invariance of domain in the way I suggested.